# Determine what number li element a div is in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <div id="test"></div>
  </li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to tell from the `div` tag what number `li` tag it's in?

I.e. in the `div` there is a javascript function that returns `2` since it's inside the second `li` element.

I realise I could go:

- get parent `ul`
- check each `li` child until the div is found.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use different variations of jQuery [index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
 $('li').index( $('li:has(div)') );
```

or

```
 $('li:has(div)').index();
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/98p2051u/1/)

Comment: Why not `$('li:has(div)').index()`?

Comment: You are welcome. Those code snippets work differently and can return different values (based on the markup). This should show the difference: https://jsfiddle.net/98p2051u/2/

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jQuery .find();](https://api.jquery.com/find/) something like :

```
<ul class="level-1">
  <li class="item-i">I</li>
  <li class="item-ii">II
      <div class="text">this is the div</div>
    </li>
      <li class="item-c">C</li>
  <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>
```

> $("ul.level-1").find( "div" ).css( "background-color", "yellow" );

Depends what you need ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the index of the `li`, since index is zero based add 1 to it to get 2

```
var $div = $('#test')
var index = $div.parent().index() + 1
```